# Font Awesome icons not working in succession

Tags: html, wordpress, font-awesome

I'm trying to add font awesome icons to my wordpress site using the Stratford theme. When I add them in the page it looks fine in the editor (see below) but if I preview or publish the page it messes the page up a lot.

[Green FA icons and text exactly how I want it to appear, in the editor view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myvS1.png)

[The same page but after I click "Preview" or publish it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzSQm.png)

I tried contacting Wordpress support they told me to contact Font Awesome, and FA pointed me to here, where i couldn't find a similar issue

Comment: how to you apply the icon ? Do you use the html tag `<i class="fad fa-acorn"></i>`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't include the code. Here it is:  <p><span style="color:#008000" class="has-inline-color"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Websites &amp; Apps</p>

Comment: Can you add your html and css to the question above? You're adding "has-inline-color" to the span but I don't see where the span closes.

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the `<span>` tag.

Any non-void elements has to be open and closed.

```
<p> <!--open p tag-->
<span style="color:#008000" class="has-inline-color"> <!--open span tag-->
<i class="fas fa-check"></i>
Websites &amp; Apps
</span> <!--close span tag-->
</p> <!--close p tag-->
```

Comment: Thank you, I will double-check that but I'm 95% sure I just copied the code over wrong.